# How read all files in the folder and replace the pattern in file using Groovy

Tags: groovy

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import java.io.File;
def list = []
def dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\CodeTest")

    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) 
         { 
            file ->list << file
         }
    list.each 
        {
            println it.path
        }
//Replace the pattern in file and write to file sequentially.
def replacePatternInFile(file, Closure replaceText)
    {
            file.write(replaceText(file.text))
    }   
def file = new File(file)
def patternToFind1 = ~/</
def patternToFind2 = ~/>/
def patternToReplace1 = '&lt'
def patternToReplace2 = '&gt'

//Call the method
replacePatternInFile(file){
    it.replaceAll(patternToFind1,patternToReplace1) 
}

replacePatternInFile(file){
    it.replaceAll(patternToFind2,patternToReplace2) 
}

println file.getText()
```

I am able to change the pattern for one file but I want to read all the files in the folder and replace the pattern in each file one by one 
while executing it:
ERROR:An error occurred [Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(java.util.ArrayList)], see error log for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many problems with your code...

1) You don't need to import:

```
import java.io.File;
```

2) When you call:

```
def file = new File(file)
```

There is no variable called `file` in `new File(file)` (did you mean `files`?)

3) If you did mean `new File(files)` then that is where your error is...  You can't make a new file from a list of Strings

4) The entity for `>` is `&gt;` NOT `&gt`...  The same for `<` (it needs a semicolon at the end)

You will need to iterate your list of Strings (`files.each { path ->` ?) and then work on each one in turn.

Though 2) and 3) make me suspect that the above code isn't your real code, but a pretend copy from memory (or a badly redacted copy), as the above code will not give you the error you say you're getting

Comment: Thanks I did the changes